# Why are users listed as having 0 reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation

I thought I saw people with 0 reputation on Stack Overflow:

[image: Screenshot of users page, with some having 0 rep]

How is that even possible? I started with 1.

Comment: Do you have links to those people? As far as I'm aware it's *not* possible.

Comment: "I have seen a couple of people with 0 reputation on stackoverflow". Links please.

Comment: Do you have an example, because that shouldn't be possible. Even a suspended User has 1 reputation point. Are you sure it was the overall reputation and not the gained reputation, like here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=4994&tab=reputation&filter=week (just a random page of gained reputation in the current week)?

Comment: I **have** seen people with 0 and negative reputation for week/month/year. That's when they lose reputation within that time period. But never for total reputation, as that's capped to a minimum of 1.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I think that is probably what I saw.

Comment: The close reason, non-repo, isn't correct. I can reproduce it, with different users of course, any time, on almost any site. Go to the `Users` page, select the `Reputation` or `Voters` tab, select any sub-tab, except `All`, then go through the pages until you find a user, or users, that have `0`, or any negative number, in their rep. Sample screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XElwF.png). The [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298211/351780#comment-968066) by [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) explains why such numbers are possible.

Comment: Those aren't reputation numbers, those are their weekly rep earnings...

Answer (score 11):

It isn't.  There is no way of having 0 reputation.

Comment: Also note the OP's screenshot is of their weekly (IIRC) rep increase, not their overall rep.

Comment: @Akaisteph7: No particular individual is downvoting more than once. Voting is purely the expression of individuals and, above anything else, must not be taken personally.

Comment: It's the way Meta works. But I see you've hit the rep floor (!!), so no real harm done.